# Swift with Parse: Error when adding push notification support to appDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add parse to my appDelegate with Swift. I get an error saying

> Cannot invoke 'registerForRemoteNotifications' with an argument list of type '(UIUserNotificationType)'

Here's my code. What's wrong?

```
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications(types)
    }
    return true
```

Comment: You're wrote two times `
application.registerForRemoteNotifications(OoO)` but each times differently. One with nothing as OoO, the other one with a flags of `UIUserNotificationSettings`. The last one seems wrong according to your message. Seems that you wanted :`registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)` (in the else test)

Comment: The latter - so Xcode says - is not working...

Comment: Because types changed too in iOS8. Before, it was `UIRemoteNotificationType` and not `UIUserNotificationType` => `let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've followed the Parse tutorial for setting up Push Notifications and Certificates with the Apple Developer Console, make sure your `AppDelegate.swift` looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("ID", clientKey:"KEY")

    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
        UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
        UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.addUniqueObject("Chat", forKey: "channels")
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

This last function resets the badge counter when the user opens the app:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    //Reset badge counter to zero
    var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    if(currentInstallation.badge != 0){
        currentInstallation.badge = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

This could be useful if you're using Swift 2.0, due to some error saying

> binary operator cannot apply to two UIUserNotificationType